# What browser settings can cause server encoding issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to reproduce an exception my rails site generates whenever a specific crawler hits a certain page:

ActionView::Template::Error:incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

The page takes GET parameters. When I visit the page with the same GET parameters with my browser, everything renders correctly.

The IP of the crawler is always EU-based (my site is US-based), and one of the user agents is:

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GrapeshotCrawler/2.0; +http://www.grapeshot.co.uk/crawler.php)

Looking at the HTTP headers sent, the only difference I see between my browser requests and the crawler's is it includes HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET, whereas mine does not:

-- HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: utf-8,iso-8859-1;q=0.7,*;q=0.6

I tried setting this in my request but I couldn't reproduce. Are there HTTP header params that can change how rails renders? Are there any other settings I can try to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a browser, more likely an automatic crawler. In fact, if you follow the link in the user agent you get the following explanation

> The Grapeshot crawler is an automated robot that visits pages to examine and analyse the content, in this sense it is somewhat similar to the robots used by the major search engine companies.

Unless the crawler is submitting a POST request (which is really unlikely as crawlers tend to follow links via GET and not to issue POST requests), it means the crawler is somehow injecting some information in your page which causes your controller to crash.

The most common cause is a malformed query string. Check the query string associated with the request: it's likely it contains a not-UTF8 encoded character that is read by your controller and somehow it's crashing it.

It's also worth to inspect the stacktrace of the exception (either in the Rails logs or using a third party apps such as Bugsnag) to determine what component of your stack is causing the exception, reproduce, test and fix it.

Comment: Yes, I have gathered as much. But I cannot reproduce the problem. The parameters are pretty simple: utf8=✓&query_string=misty. How can I get my browser to send that in another encoding? Are there any other http headers/settings I can set to tweak that?

Comment: Check the stack trace and use one of the exception tracking tool I suggested. In this way you can collect the entire environment.